# Can we use amp youtube tag inside amp story grid layer tag

Tags: amp-html, amp-youtube

How can I show youtube video in AMP story code? I am using amp-youtube inside amp-story-grid-layer for it, but the validator is showing error

**Tag 'amp-youtube' is disallowed as the child of tag 'amp-story-page'**

Comment: I just want to know how i use **youtube** in 'amp-story' tag

Comment: download and use <amp-video>

Answer (score 3):

As the errors states it is not allowed to use `amp-youtube` as a children of `amp-story-grid-layer` - also see the [list of allowed elements](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-story#children)